# Codemagic IOS build failure | The relationship 'devices' is required but was not provided with this request

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

POST https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/profiles returned 409: Relationship is required but was not provided. - The relationship 'devices' is required but was not provided with this request.

[image: IOS build fail]

Comment: bundles are retrived fine during the workfolw update.

Comment: Only the build is coming with this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use development certificates and profiles (for mobile applications), it is required that you have at least one existing mobile device on the Apple Developer Portal registered.

Check if you have something on this list:
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list

If not, then adding a device should fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @Arnold Veltman,
    I have my MacBook listed in this link. Still do you think I should add more device.

Comment: Hi @Aravind, as you are building a mobile application, you should also be required to add a mobile testing device when creating a provisioning profile.

Currently, it seems that an attempt is made to create the provisioning profile, but it does not go through, as there are no suitable devices.

Likewise, I cannot create one manually on Apple Developer Portal when I do not include any mobile devices. Edited the answer above to specify.

Comment: Hi @Arnold Veltmann,
    I am facing a further error which I posted in the below link.
    Can you please look into it?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471089/ios-build-failure-in-codemagic-due-to-cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versio