# ios build failure in codemagic due to CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit"

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I am creating a workflow in code magic for my flutter app.
I am able to build the app from my local machine for both Android and IOS.
In codemagic the android build is successful but the IOS build is failing.
Below is the log. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        FBSDKCoreKit (= 14.1.0)

      In Podfile:
        flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.3.0, which depends on
          FBSDKCoreKit (~> 13)


    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * changed the constraints of dependency `FBSDKCoreKit` inside your development pod `flutter_facebook_auth`.
       You should run `pod update FBSDKCoreKit` to apply changes you've made.

    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'



Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I followed the below steps to resolve this issue.

1. Delete the ios/pods.lock file in the workspace.
2. Execute the below commands.

   `pod repo update`

   `pod install --repo-update`

   `pod update FBSDKCoreKit`
3. Commit the changes in the workspace to repo.
4. Trigger the build again in codemagic

Answer (score 0):

Lower the version of facebook events to 0.14.0 in pubspec.yaml. And try again.

Comment: Hi Kaushik,
    I do not have a facebookevents dependency in my pubspec.yml

Comment: Sorry facebook auth version. Lower it in pubspec.yaml

Comment: Hi Kaushik,
    I am not using any facebook related dependencies. I found the issue. Posting it now.

Comment: Ohoh. Then delete podfile.lock, delete pods folder and .symlinks folder. Run pod install and try again